# Rails Production Pre-compile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to pre-compile assets for Production it gives the following error, please help me out with this i need to make a release..,

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (): [/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/b...]
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `sh'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `ruby'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: looks like the real error is swallowed somehow... the command did not even have a return status. strange!

Comment: exactly this is irritating

Comment: the asset task calls itself again from rake. that is a potential point of failure. you could try to debug into this using pry or the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, It was issue of my CPU, CPU was on top 100% and the pre compile process was timed out of que processes.

I have stopped all the remaining running processes and compiled, assets got compiled perfectly .,

thank you @phoet